# contact form using phpmailer via SMTP working on localhost but not on server

Tags: smtp, localhost, phpmailer

- List item

  ```
      $mail->isSMTP();
      $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
      $mail->Port = 587;
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                               
      $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com';                 
      $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxx';                           

      $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
      $mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com');     
      $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);

      $mail->isHTML(true);         
      $mail->Subject='Intending to: '.$_POST['option'];                        
      $mail->Body='<h1 align=center> Name :'.$_POST['name'].'<br>Email: '.$_POST['email'].
      '<br>Message: '.$_POST['text'].'</h1>';
      $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

      if(!$mail->send()) {
          $result="Something went wrong. Please try again.";
      }
      else {
          $result="Thank You ".$_POST['name']." for contacting us. We'll get back to you soon!";
      }
  }
  ```

  ?>
  //the error I am getting is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /storage/ssd4/215/7577215/public_html/index.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd4/215/7577215/public_html/index.php on line 5

//This only happens when the file is on the server, on localhost the mail is sent just fine.

Comment: Most current version (as of Feb 2018) does not have `PHPMailerAutoload` anymore. Removed it and try again

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the PHPMailer classes too, not just your script.

You’re also using an obsolete version of PHPMailer; get the latest from GitHub.

Comment: I am using 5.2 stable. Should I use the master branch instead?

Comment: Yes. Look at the tagged releases too. You should be using composer to load it.